# Maclaurin Series (How to show?)

Tags: calculus

Determine the Maclaurin's expansion for $\sec x-\tan x$, up to and including the term in $x^3$. Show that, to this degree of approximation, $\sec x-\tan x$ can be expressed as $a+b\ln (1+x)$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants to be determined.

I don't know for the last part, how to show that $a+b\ln (1+x)$?

Comment: You might try to expand $\ln{(1+x)}$ into Maclaurin series with same degree and compare the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you have the MacLauring series for two functions $f$ and $g$ up to some order $k$, and that both match, what can you say about approximating $f(x)$ by $g(x)$ (up to that order) around $0$?

Answer (score 0):

Write out the Maclaurin series for $a+b\ln(1+x)$. Match the first few (couple of) terms to obtain a value for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the McLaurin series of $\ln(1+x)$, multiply by $b$, and $a$. Then match to the McLaurin series of $\sec x-\tan x$.